# Unable to update a jquery script downloaded from github

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio-player

I'm new to using jQuery.

I'm attempting to setup a local installation of code called 'scm-music-player' which I found on github.. There is a version of the script that works great using the author's server, the code seems to have external links to outdated jQuery scripts, I located within the zip file I download the files, but I just can not get it to work, I've been at it for days now.

Here is what I've done so far:

1. Downloaded files from here https://github.com/cshum/scm-music-player/archive/github.zip
2. Extracted & uploaded to my server root directory https://mohdish.com
3. Then ran the configuration script as advised http://scmplayer.co/#base=https://mohdish.com/

This generates a block of code:

Installed the generated script shown below in my index.php at the start of the script. It didn't work Next looked through the scripts and noticed that the config.js (root folder) file had outdated external links. I found all the scripts that were being referenced to on my server from the zip file I then made several attempts at modifying config.js with no success. All the links below point to the correct location, but I must be missing something.

This is what part of that looks like now: `paths: {'jquery': 'https://mohdish.com/js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js','jquery.ui': 'https://mohdish.com/js/lib/jquery/jquery-ui.min.js','jquery.scrollto':'https://mohdish.com/js/lib/jquery/jquery.scrollTo.min.js','underscore': 'https://mohdish.com/js/lib/underscore/underscore.js', 'knockout':'https://mohdish.com/js/lib/knockout/knockout-2.1.0.js','text': 'https://mohdish.com/lib/require/text.js','domready': 'https://mohdish.com/lib/require/domready.js'},`

Anyone able to give me some advice?

```
<!-- SCM Music Player http://scmplayer.co -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://mohdish.com/script.js"
        data-config="{'skin':'skins/aquaBlue/skin.css','volume':50,'autoplay':false,'shuffle':false,'repeat':1,'placement':'top','showplaylist':false,'playlist':[{'title':'Million Dreams','url':'https://mohdish.com/ziv.mp3'}]}" ></script>
<!-- SCM Music Player script end -->
```

This is what I've modified, I am sure I've done something wrong!

```
{'jquery': 'https://mohdish.com/js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js','jquery.ui': 'https://mohdish.com/js/lib/jquery/jquery-ui.min.js','jquery.scrollto':'https://mohdish.com/js/lib/jquery/jquery.scrollTo.min.js','underscore': 'https://mohdish.com/js/lib/underscore/underscore.js', 'knockout':'https://mohdish.com/js/lib/knockout/knockout-2.1.0.js','text': 'https://mohdish.com/lib/require/text.js','domready': 'https://mohdish.com/lib/require/domready.js'},
```

I expected it to work the same as it does on the author's server.

Comment: please specify if "the author's server" is http://scmplayer.co/ or not. Also, please annotate the pieces of code you've shown before them (*This is what I've modified, I am sure I've done something wrong!* – is this about the bit above or below? please annotate both) *part of that looks like now* – this not a clear annotation, too, what is *that*? After *This generates a block of code:* the code seems to be missing, please insert it. In general, please be sure to provide a [mcve]. Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I did a lot of posts reading on Google, realised that I was incorrect in adding .js to the file path, when I took this off & corrected the path to the correct folders then the player started working,  well on desktop devices anyway.  Just need to work out why my site does not play on mobile devices.